# DDD scores between all profiles (graph). Where/when to calculate AVG efficiently?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a bounded context `Profiles` that manages `n` profiles in a graph-like fashion. Based on profiles' information it calculates a score for each edge in the graph (i.e. for each pair of profiles), making it `n*n` scores. When a profile `p` is updated (event `ProfileUpdate`) it re-calculates the scores of `p` with all other profiles (`n-1` events `ScoreUpdate`).

Another BC `Account` is interested in the *average score* `AVG(p)` of an account's associated profile. For this, it keeps the profile's `id` and **I wonder how and where to handle calculation and/or storage of `AVG` per profile** in an **efficient** way.

## My thoughts so far

**Aproach 1: Pre-Calculate & Batching**

Naively, the `Profiles` BC is responsible for the scoring, hence I would put `AVG` calculation in this domain and emit `AVGUpdate` A LOT (more often than `ScoreUpdate` occures, with optimization at least `n` times per `ProfileUpdate`). The `Account` BC would just store the `AVG` and be able to show it on demand.

But this feels very in-efficient. Normally, we see **some** `ProfileUpdate` events, that result in **A LOT** of `ScoreUpdate` events and the `Account` BC rather **seldom** wants to show `AVG` and I am worried about the overhead/performance of handling the huge amount of `AVGUpdate` and all the involved DB-work to be done in `Account` BC.

If `Account` BC handles each `AVGUpdate` on its own it would need `n` queries per `ProfileUpdate` which makes it unacceptably expensive to host that service. So I wonder if we should batch the `AVGUpdate` events but then again I am worried about the size per event (probably not a good idea to put `n` scores in a single event and paging event batches feels strange as well).

But to me it feels just strange that some users update their profiles and in turn all accounts will update and even override their `AVG`s a lot before the account's owner looks at it weeks later. That just makes it unnecessary to calculate & store the intermediate `AVG`s of that account.

**Aproach 2: On Demand**

Since `Account` BC seldom shows the `AVG` we could rather calculate it *on demand*. Since there are A LOT of `ScoreUpdate` events, we would not like to react on each of these to re-calculate the average, because of the overhead. Rather, we would like to calculate it on-demand, but this puts the overhead of having events such as `TRIGGER_AVG_CALCULATION` and `AVG_RESULT` and obviously is bad for UX as the user would need to wait and could suffer from worse service degradation.

## Questions

How would you approach this scenario? Any other arguments torwards the approaches or even other ideas for approaches?

Comment: What other Profile information does Account need to retrieve? How long does it actually take to calculate the average score?

Comment: The more specific use case is that a dashboard for the account shows the AVG (and MAX) of scores among other metrics and information from other services/BCs. Calculating the avg score is in few `ms` and optimized on the data layer itself, but of course it will take longer the more profiles exist.

Answer (score 1):

So if i read you correctly the main thing you want to avoid is sending/dealing with an AvgUpdate event each time a single profile vs profile score changes?

I can see why your matching would generate an exponential amount of updates, as each time a profile changes any linked profiles will have their average score changed.

I see thee ways around this.

1. Simply rate limit the AvgUpate messages per profile, only send when the score significantly changes, or once every hour or whatever criteria best fits your needs.

   Obviously this reduces the accuracy of any given query of averages.
2. change the definition of 'average' so that you can recalc the avg from the current avg and a single ScoreUpdate event.

   ie. If you store, `totalMatchesEver` and `currentAvgScore` then a new ScoreUpdate can change the `avgHistoricalMatchScore` which might be equally suitable for your purposes and easier to calculate
3. Store individual profile vs profile scores with the Profile, and calculate the average on the fly.

   This makes the average calculation on demand, fast and usable as a selection criteria in a database. But doesn't scale well.

Comment: In 1) checking for significant changes is a good idea to prevent unneccessary events! In 2) I think it suffers from expenential growth as well, because the count of `ScoreUpdate` is exponential? In 3) I do not yet understand what you mean by *"individual profile vs profile scores"*. We have a DB in the BC `Profile` that stores the scores for all pairs of profiles (n * n).

Comment: that is essentially what i mean `id,profileid,profile2id,score` then `select avg(score) where profileid=x`

Comment: since you are already sending scoreupdate, if you can make the avg calc easy then you should be good

Comment: But then it suffers from the same problem, updating the DB on each `ScoreUpdate` is slow and the table needs exponential size again (besides the Profile BC of course storing that huge amount of data)

Comment: yeah the db doesnt scale well, changing the definition  is your best bet if its need to be upto date

Comment: Yes, I am more into limiting the `AVGUpdate` (both semantic optimizations e.g. when avg did not change) and rate limiting (e.g. storing for each profile when the last update was send). Also I thought of trigger an update as result of a login, so the data is fresh.